# How to solve a double quadratic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, radicals, nested-radicals

I have a double quadratic inequality of the form $2x^4 + 2x^2 - 3 < 0 $. Had it been *equation* rather than *inequality* I would have probably set $x^2 = z$ and looked for the solution in terms of z and finally in terms of x. But how to deal with this inequality?

Answer (score 7):

You can complete the square:
$$2\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{7}{2}<0,$$
or
$$\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2<\frac{7}{4}$$
Can you see how to solve this?

Comment: That is where I am stuck. How can I deal with this inequality?

Comment: Solving $(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{7}{4}$ gives $x^2=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$, so $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}<x^2<-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$.

Comment: You can ignore the lower bound, since $x^2\geq 0$ for all real numbers $x$. So you just need to solve $0\leq  x^2<-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's $$x^2<\frac{-1+\sqrt{7}}{2}$$ or
$$-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{7}}{2}}<x<\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{7}}{2}}.$$